# Symfony 3 functional tests - custom request class

Tags: php, symfony, testing, symfony-3.1

I'm writing functional tests for my Symfony 3 application and I have a problem that every method in controller accepts only custom request, not default `Request` class, which is used in the BrowserKit crawler. How can I mock custom Request class in the Symfony 3 crawler or do it in the other way?

Here is my code:

ListController.php

```
public function listAction(CustomRequest $request) 
{
return $this->render('list.html.twig');
}
```

ListControllerTest.php

```
 $client = static::createClient();
 $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/list/');
```

When I'm running test I'm receiving:

```
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Controller\ListController::listAction() must be an instance of AppBundle\Component\Http\CustomRequest, instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request given
```

Here is my app.php. Here I'm replacing the stanard request method:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$request = CustomRequest::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
```